# Loop the mouse when you press q python

Tags: python, keyboard

I would like to make click in loop when I press the q key, but idk why i have an error

code :

```
import keyboard

def autoclicker():
    i = 0
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            i = i + 1
            print(i)
            keyboard.press_and_release('<Button-1>')


autoclicker()
```

Error :

```
ValueError: ("Key '<ButtonPress-1>' is not mapped to any known key.", ValueError("Key name '<buttonpress-1>' is not mapped to any known key."))
```

Comment: Because "<Button-1>" is not a keyboard key

Comment: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python Have a look at that, uses the `mouse` module